# Is there a way to write to a file on server in react one page app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Long story short I was asked to create an interface for an API in my internship. Then I don't know why i decided to try react and made a one page static app with it. Now my supervisor wants to keep a log of how people are using the site. Basically I want to add one more line to a file on server everytime a specific button is clicked. I found no answer for this except with a server like nodejs+express. I can add that but I am wondering if its possible without implementing a server myself. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on how you are serving the app. React itself (or any client side code) cannot write to the server directly. You can expose an api on the server which is called when the user visits and writes a log etc.

Comment: I created a docker image of the app and it runs npm start inside. Is it a bad way to serve the app?

Comment: Yes and no. npm start is mostly intended for development purposes. You will need to get an understand of how a web server works. I recommend doing a course on node/express. I'll give you the fastest way to do this (not necessarily proper)

Comment: Thanks I have some experience on express already but I was confused about how serverless react app works. I guess i will implement another app just to listen the logs instead of adding a server to my existing app.

Comment: React is just regular javascript that has a nice build process. `npm start` just creates a simple server to serve the react files (which are html/javascript). If you run npm build, you'll see files being created in the dist directory. This is effectively the react code that is served in a webserver. You can put the dist files in an experss app public directory and it'll run there just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible and that is by design. If you want to track user events without a backend, try using a third-party integration like [amplitude](https://amplitude.com/)

Comment: Or https://www.hotjar.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Shortest Way:**
Use apache to create a web server and you can access the logs from the apache directory.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html

Get apache from here and install it on your system. I am assuming you're using windows

Place your app after building (`npm run build`) into the `htdocs` directory. 
Check apache access logs to see visitor info

**Proper Way:**

Create an express app and expose an api: `/log_visit`
in log_visit, store the request ip, page etc into a database(or file)

Send /log_visit an ajax request everytime your react page changes